# Использование данных аутентификации в JUnit тестах

Tags: java, junit, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Имеется Maven проект REST API клиента, который генеририруется с помощью Maven плагина [openapi-generator-maven-plugin](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin). Также генерируются тесты, которые выполняются на стороне GitLab. GitLab версии 13.12.15 установлен во внутренней сети предпиятия на Windows машине. Аутентификация в REST API выполняется по Bearer токену, который конечно должен присутствовать во время выполнения тестов. GitLab настроен таким образом, что к коду имеют доступ много сотрудников, а к настройкам репозитория только администраторы.

Вопрос: каким образом использовать Bearer токен таким образом, чтоб во время выполнения тестов он был доступен, но в то же время не присуствовал в коде в открытом виде?

---

Была мысль использовать для этого [GitLab CI/CD variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables), так как в настройках переменной [можно указать](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#mask-a-cicd-variable) на необходимость скрытия значения переменной в логах, но каким образом передать/использовать это значение в JUnit тестах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

переменная должна автоматически передаваться в переменные окружения, которую можно прочитать в junit примерно так:

```
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    testToken = System.getenv("TEST_TOKEN");
}
```

Comment: Всё как обычно - "а ларчик просто открывался" :)